# In canon, has anyone other than Hagrid been expelled?

Tags: harry-potter, hogwarts

The following sentence from [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/127541/why-are-hogwarts-students-threatened-with-expulsion-so-much) got me thinking.

> Being expelled has extreme consequences, as we see with Hagrid - your wand is snapped and you're consigned to a life on the confines of wizarding society.

I saw this and thought "well, Hagrid living on the confines of wizarding society might have been more to do with his being half-giant than his having been expelled". But if he's the only expelled student we know of, then we have insufficient data to draw such a conclusion. **Do we know of anyone else who's been expelled from Hogwarts?**

[This question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/119874/what-does-it-take-to-be-expelled-from-hogwarts) claims Hagrid is the only one we know of, but provides no sources, and the answer doesn't address this point, so it's not a duplicate.

<sub>Canon answers only, please: all 10 books, Pottermore, and JKR quotes are acceptable sources, but no fanfic!</sub>

Comment: I take it the movies are fanfic then.

Comment: Hagrid became a gamekeeper's assistant immediately after expulsion if memory serves. He only rose to the rank of COMC teacher due to the kindness of Dumbledore. So his social status is clearly tied to his expulsion in my mind.

Comment: This question is also related (albeit it stems from JKR tweets). http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/124877/how-did-newt-graduate-from-hogwarts-if-he-got-expelled

Comment: @anaranjada No, the movies are nonsense. ;-)

Comment: @anaranjada [Yes](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/198?m=29403197#29403197).

Comment: @anaranjada And a fairly bad fanfic, at that.

Comment: @anaranjada - But an *expensive* fanfic.

Comment: But an _on-topic_ fanfic.

Comment: @MrLister Fanfics *are* on-topic.

Comment: @Randal'Thor _[I know!](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/9193/4495)_

Comment: @Randal'Thor: I would suggest taking that into chat ;P

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Just to one-up Jonah's answer,

### Yes, all the Muggle-borns

In *Deathly Hallows*, when the Dark Lord openly takes control of the Ministry of Magic, all Muggle-born wizards are considered criminals and can be imprisoned.  The Muggle-borns that evade capture must live as fugitives, and there are wizards called Snatchers hunting them.  The Muggle-born students, such as Dean Thomas, are definitely not allowed to study in Hogwarts anymore.  This wasn't as brief as Harry's other expulsion: it has lasted for most of the school year.

Comment: I like this. Of course, this might *also* be the Ministry overstepping its powers, but I don't think Voldemort cares.

Comment: It's also not entirely clear whether they were formally expelled.

Comment: @Richard: that's a valid point, I'll have to look for a specific quotation in the book later.

Comment: you cant get expelled if your not ---allowed--- inellegable to go to school legally anyway

Comment: @Himarm - Indeed. Presumably Harry was excluded in his [seventh year](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Seventh_year), what with being the most wanted Wizard in England.

Comment: @Richard Can the Dark Lord or his minions be bothered with *paperwork*?

Comment: @Michael - If history has taught us anything, it's that those who enjoy paperwork are always drawn to pure evil...

Answer (score 52):

According to the latest trailer for "Fantastic Beasts", **Newt Scamander** was expelled before completing his education

> "*... Kicked out of Hogwarts for endangering human life with a beast...*"

---

Since you're after canon quotes, JKR was kind enough to [confirm that he was indeed expelled](https://twitter.com/jk_rowling/status/719550328828522496)

> **JKR:** *Dumbledore was a young teacher **at the time Newt was expelled**. He wasn't able to revoke expulsions.*

Comment: Apparently, "endangering human life with a beast" is the only reason people get expelled.

Comment: @ibid Well, at least it's a pretty _good_ reason.

Comment: @WillihamTotland - Dumbledore never thought so.

Comment: @ibid - In fairness, Dumbledore spends most of the book series using small children as expendable pawns in his neverending fight to murder an ex-student. Expelling people for minor infractions of the school rules seems quite hypocritical when you look at his sins.

Comment: I think characterizing killing Voldemort as murdering an ex-student leaves out some important details.

Comment: Death of Hitler: Ex-painter driven to suicide by U.S. invasion.

Comment: It's natural for @Richard to characterize things like that. He was sorted into Slytherin.

Comment: @Ellesedil - I most certainly was not.

Comment: Meh kids are expendable, remember when the catholics sent the children to kill the muslems...

Answer (score 44):

### Yes: Harry Potter

> Dear Mr Potter,
>
> We have received intelligence that you performed the Patronus Charm at
> twenty-three
> minutes past nine this evening in a Muggle-inhabited area and in the
> presence of a
> Muggle.
> The severity of this breach of the Decree for the Reasonable
> Restriction of Underage
> Sorcery **has resulted in your expulsion
> from Hogwarts School of Witchcraft and Wizardry.** Ministry
> representatives will be
> calling at your place of residence shortly to destroy your wand.
> As you have already received an official warning for a previous
> offence under Section 13
> of the International Confederation of Warlocks' Statute of Secrecy, we
> regret to inform
> you that your presence is required at a disciplinary hearing at the
> Ministry of Magic at 9
> a.m. on the twelfth of August.
>
> —*Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix*

In the fifth book, **Harry was briefly expelled from Hogwarts, due to having performed the Patronus Charm in front of a Muggle.** The expulsion was later reversed pending a hearing.

> Following discussions with the Headmaster of Hogwarts School of
> Witchcraft and Wizardry, the Ministry has agreed that the question of
> your expulsion will also be decided at that time. You should therefore
> consider yourself suspended from school  pending further enquiries.
>
> —*Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix*

This expulsion, was, however, an instance of the Ministry overstepping its authority:

> 'The Ministry does not have the power to expel Hogwarts students,
> Cornelius, as I reminded you on the night of the second of August,'
> said Dumbledore. 'Nor does it have the right to confiscate wands until
> charges have been successfully proven....
>
> —*Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix*

Comment: It was repealed.

Comment: That expulsion was invalid though, as proven by the very next owl to arrive.

Comment: @Richard - Yes, it was repealed.

Comment: @Randal'Thor - It wasn't really invalid, merely *very* short.

Comment: It's also not clear that he was actually expelled. The follow up states that his expulsion is up for discussion.

Comment: @Richard - I think there's good reason to think he was. The letter was probably from Mafalda Hopkirk (right?). She's fair and knows the law. I doubt Fudge was fudging anything.

Comment: @Jonah The way I understood it, the immediate expulsion was invalid, hence why they had to change it to a possible expulsion dependent on a hearing. If immediate expulsion had been a real possibility, would even Dumbledore have been able to talk the Ministry out of that option?

Comment: @Richard - Scratch that. The expulsion *was* actually on Fudge's orders and probably illegal. I still think it counts though.

Comment: @Randal'Thor The way I read it, the hearing was to discuss possible disciplinary action in addition to the expulsion.

Comment: @TGnat From one of the quotes in Jonah's answer: "Following discussions with the Headmaster of Hogwarts School of Witchcraft and Wizardry, the Ministry has agreed that **the question of your expulsion will also be decided at that time.**"

Comment: "'The Ministry does not have the power to expel Hogwarts students, Cornelius, as I reminded you on the night of the second of August,' said Dumbledore. 'Nor does it have the right to confiscate wands until charges have been successfully proven....", the ministry "expelled" harry, however, since the ministry doesnt actually have that power, Harry was never in fact expelled from hogwarts, he was just "told" he was expelled

Comment: its like a US cop pulling you over in the UK and giving you a ticket, i mean he told you that you have a ticket, but you dont really have a ticket since a US cop has 0 power in the UK. Harry had a letter claiming he was expelled, but the powers that be at hogwarts could give a rats ass about that letter, since harry was infact, never expelled

Answer (score 0):

Besides for Hagrid (and Harry as mentioned in [another answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/127577/100430)) there are no other explicit expulsions from Hogwarts mentioned in the seven storyline books.

There is one other expulsion mentioned in the books, but it is an expulsion from Durmstrang. In *Deathly Hallows* Chapter 18 we find out that Grindelwald was expelled from Durmstrang, but this obviously does not count as being expelled from Hogwarts (although this specification is not mentioned in the question title).

> (This was  your mistake at Durmstrang! But I do not complain,  because
>   if you had not been expelled, we would never  have met.)

-

> Grindelwald, expelled from Durmstrang for  near-fatal attacks upon
>   fellow students, fled the  country hours after the girl’s death, and
>   Albus (out of  shame or fear?) never saw him again, not until forced 
>   to do so by the pleas of the Wizarding world.

Comment: It's unclear to me how this answers the question. This seems to answer a separate question about a list of students expelled at other schools/all schools.

Comment: It answers the question by stating that in the primary part of the cannon no one else has been expelled from Hogwarts. That the answer also mentions that one person was expelled form another school is a bonus.

Comment: The bonus appears to be over 75% of the content of the answer, that seems to be the main focus of the answer, and not just a "cursory addition", so again. I don't see how the _majority_ of this post provides an answer to the question.

Comment: @Edlothiad Though perhaps in line with [this](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11998/100430) I should remove that part in case anyone ever asks if anyone was expelled from another school.

Comment: @Edlothiad I also did note that it directly answers the question as phrased in the title.

Comment: @Edlothiad Though I have now edited slightly to more clearly differentiate between the two parts.